# Cannot import postprocessing from Three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

Whenever I try to run this code inside my React app it fails and says:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { extend, useThree, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer'
import { ShaderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass'
import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass'
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass'
import { FilmPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/FilmPass'

extend({ EffectComposer, ShaderPass, RenderPass, UnrealBloomPass, FilmPass });

export default function Effects() {
    const { gl, scene, camera, size } = useThree();
    const composer = useRef();
    useEffect(() => void composer.current.setSize(size.width, size.height), [size]);
    useFrame(() => composer.current.render(), 2);

    return (
        <effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
            <renderPass attachArray="passes" scene={scene} camera={camera} />
            <unrealBloomPass attachArray="passes" args={[undefined, 1.8, 1, 0]} />
        </effectComposer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you try with .js ? e.g. `from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js'`

Comment: @soju Yeah, doesn't work :(

Comment: Any chances to share your entire app as a live example or GitHub repository?

Comment: Did you try to remove all the code except the imports ?

Answer (score 1):

three/jsm has untranspiled import statements that dont work in node/next/gatsby. all three have remedies for this. for instance next has dynamic imports https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import you'll also find lots of issues for this since it's a very common problem people bump into https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9890